# See if 2 arrays contain same element (swift 2.0)

Tags: arrays, swift

I have 2 arrays of strings. For example, let's say this:

```
 let array1 = ["string1", "string2", "string3", "string4", "string5"]
 let array2 = ["string8", "string4", "string3", "string367", "string5"]
```

I want to compare and see if the 2 arrays contain any of the same elements, and then place the result into an array of bools. Like say "the first element in array1 is "string1", now let's go through and see if any element in array2 is the same as "string1", if they are, the first element in the boolArray will be true, if not, it will be false." The result of doing this for comparing array1 to array2 here would yield a boolArray of

```
  var boolArray = [false, false, true, true, true]
```

How can I do this? I tried this:

```
for y in array1 {
        for z in array2 {
            if y == z {
                self.boolArray.append(true)
            }
            else {
                self.boolArray.append(false)
            }
        }
    }
```

but it didn't work, as the boolArray contained 25 elements, and it should only contain 5. Maybe there is some swift function that I am not aware of that does a lot of this for us?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
for y in array1 {
        self.boolValue = false
        for z in array2 {
            if y == z {
                    self.boolValue = true
            }
        }
        self.boolArray.append(self.boolValue)
    }
```

Using your existing code as a baseline, you only want to write to the boolean array AFTER you finish iterating through your comparator array (Array 2). This is a very iterative approach but should work.

Comment: yes, this is what I was looking for. thanks a lot! it yields an array of bools that indicates whether or not the first array has a matching element in the second array.

Comment: NP. It's not the most graceful or efficient solution but using your original solution it should get the job done.

Comment: One thing that could improve the efficiency of this answer would be to add
<code> break </code>
after the you set boolValue to true

Answer (score 22):

You can use `map()` to map each element of the first array to a boolean value,
and `contains()` to check if that element is contained in the second array:

```
let array1 = ["string1", "string2", "string3", "string4", "string5"]
let array2 = ["string8", "string4", "string3", "string367", "string5"]

let boolArray = array1.map { (element) -> Bool in
    return array2.contains(element)
}
print(boolArray) // [false, false, true, true, true]
```

Using closure shorthand syntax, this can be written as

```
let boolArray = array1.map { array2.contains($0) }
```

If the second array is *large* (and the elements are `Hashable`)
then it *may* be advantageous to convert it to a `Set` first
(as in @matt's answer)

```
let set2 = Set(array2)
let boolArray = array1.map { set2.contains($0) }
```

to increase the performance of the lookup.

Comment: for future visitors, this approach works as well. I tried the other first which is why I gave it the correct answer mark (and it was easier for me to understand, being a swift novice), but it works just the same as the accepted answer. have an upvote though :)

Comment: When is an array considered large? For example, are two arrays of 30 strings each, should I be using sets instead? I have no idea what's considered large. Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

If you are content that *any* element in either array should match *any* element in the other array, then the algorithm is simple: convert both arrays to sets and take the intersection of the two sets. The resulting set will be all the elements present in both arrays.

```
let array1 = ["string1", "string2", "string3", "string4", "string5"]
let array2 = ["string8", "string4", "string3", "string367", "string5"]
let result = Set(array1).intersect(Set(array2))
```

Observe, however, that this merely answers the question about the presence of elements; it gives up the notion of order.

Comment: this is actually a cool thing in swift that I didn't know you could do (and I will probably use in the future), but it doesn't directly yield an array of bools that indicates whether or not each element has a matching element in the array it's being compared to. Thanks though!

Comment: I understand that. :) I knew it didn't meet your actual spec. Just wanted to make sure you knew about this option. It's insanely fast when this is the question you want answered.